# How to correctly retrieve Shopify inventory levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, inventory-management

I am trying to build a flow (in a web app) where Shopify shop admins can get notified when the inventory levels for a particular product is below a certain threshold in a particular location. I have looked at the [inventory_levels/update webhook](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/webhook#event-topics-inventory-levels-update) but I am in a pickle after reading [this](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-04/resources/inventorylevel).

According to the documentation, the true inventory levels for a location will only be known after the order has been fulfilled. In that case, do I have to subscribe to the [orders/fulfilled](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/webhook#event-topics-orders-fulfilled) and [order/partially_fulfilled](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/webhook#event-topics-orders-partially-fulfilled) webhooks as well ?

What is the best way to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a simple recipe like this:

- listen for an order, and cherry pick the line items sold
- using the line item, get the variant inventory item ID
- using the inventory item ID you can get inventory levels

You can get all the locations a shop has, and when you combine a location ID with an inventory item ID, you can get the levels of every SKU at every location

Not a hard recipe at all. Of course, that is one of many. Feel free to try others.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that, the true inventory levels are only known after the order has been fulfilled. That is when Shopify updated the inventory levels at the right location

Comment: Order is booked. Shopify adjusts inventory. Webhook with order goes out. You parse the order, you look into inventory. You get good number. What exactly is your problem?